# Непонятное гигантское потребление памяти Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Кто нибудь может пожалуйста объяснить непонятную для меня загадку потребления оперативный памяти Windows10 ?

Вот скриншот, на котором вроде бы хорошо видно из диспетчера задач из вкладки "процессы", что все открытие приложения потребляют максимум 6-7 Гб из 47 доступных, но во вкладке "производительность" того же диспетчера задач показывается, что памяти занято аж 40 Гб из 47.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это за чертовщина такая ?? И это не единичный случай, так постоянно.
После перезагрузки сначала все нормально, но по мере течения времени память все занимается и занимается все больше.

Comment: У тебя используется 12, а 32 - закэшировано..... возможно ты открывал что-то мутированное и оно пока лежит в кэше..... Например ты работаешь с VS Studio и что-то там читаешь в память...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer#download воспользуйтесь, она даст вам точное представление о том куда и как уходит ram

Comment: Виртуальные машины наверное есть. В списке процессов они не отображаются. Ну и малвари много - яндекс, касперский, телеграм. Мэйл-ру агента для полного набора не хватает. @АлексейШиманский Чисто кеш на диаграмме показан справа от темно-фиолетового блока.